# Question marks appear even when opening the file in correct encoded format

Tags: 7-zip, encoding, visual-studio-code

I have been looking around on StackOverflow and here in the hopes of finding out as to why certain characters turn into question marks. To be more precise: It is often letter such as `é` and `ó` etc.

I have tried multiple different solutions, such as setting it to different encoding formats, trying to find out which format was used (`UTF-8` default when opening visual studio code) and many more solutions. Unfortunately I cannot get the characters to appear. They remain question marks.

I do have to note that the file was zipped and I unzipped it with `7zip`. I then opened the file with Visual Studio Code. I cannot open it with notepad, because the file is too big for notepad to open.

To give an example:

```
Michel Tel?: Sunset (2013) (V)  [Themselves]
```

If you look it up, you'll see it's "Michel Teló". I need to inspect the file (with my own eyes) before I can make it a CSV. Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

To see the *actual* character, open the file in a [hexadecimal](https://datacadamia.com/data/type/number/hex/hex) editor, such as the free [HxD editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) from Maël Hörz (mh-nexus), or one of the [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/hxd/). A well-designed hex editor can display data of virtually *any* size, even an entire multi-terabyte HDD, by opening only *a portion* of the whole file at a time.

Here is how ë (e-umlaut) appears in *HxD* and in free *Notepad++* editor:

[image: e-umlaut in HxD]

Note that *Ma* is the string of bytes in hex, 0x4D, 0x61, but the single letter *ë* is a two-byte character, 0xC3, 0xAB.

To display such characters correctly,

1. The text editor must be able to correctly display multibyte characters, such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does.
2. The text editor must be set to use a font that *includes* those specific characters, such as Google's free [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata), used in the *Notepad++* screenshot above.

Use Windows' *Character Map* to see what is included in a font.